# Unable to print all the characters of a string by charAt() in Java?

Tags: java, string

I have a question. I am a beginner in programming and I have been stuck here for hours now. I want to know how you can read all the letters in a certain user input.

```
String naem = inPut.nextLine(); //where inPut is a "Scanner inPut = new Scanner (system.in)
nameInput = naem.charAt(0); //where nameInput is a char
System.out.println("Name: "+nameInput);
```

I am making a program where have to take input a name and all the characters of that name will be printed through `System.out.println("Name: " +nameInput);`

I'd really appreciate it if you could help out.

Comment: What do you think this `nameInput = naem.charAt(0);` does? Even your comments say it is a char...

Comment: Try looking better next time... The explanation for your misunderstanding is presented very clearly in the Java documentation:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)

Comment: `naem.charAt(0);` returns the first char in the String read from the Scanner. You know that it returns a single char (as you state `nameInput` is a char), so it seems you may misunderstand what a char is. Read about [Java Primitive Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: in eclipse it only outputs one character

Comment: @RioAblas A char is a single character. If you want the entire String (all characters), you should print naem (assuming the line read only contains the name). `System.out.println("Name: " + naem);`

Comment: @Zachary thanks. I'm still stupid and a beginner. I was absent when this as introduced soo I have little information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to print the `naem` which you are receiving by the input and not a single character which is what you'd get if you used .charAt().

Comment: thanks I'm stupid and still a beginner. I was absent when this was introduced

Answer (score 1):

```
nameInput = naem.charAt(0); //1
System.out.println("Name: "+nameInput);//2
```

What actually these two lines are doing is that :

Line 1  is taking the first character of the string and storing it into `nameInput` and then line 2 is printing it. 
Now if you want to print all the character in this way you have to go through the entire string. You can do this by using loop.

Here is an Example :

```
String naem = inPut.nextLine(); //where inPut is a "Scanner inPut = new Scanner (system.in)
    System.out.println("Name: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < naem.length(); i++)
      { 
        char nameInput = naem.charAt(i); 
        System.out.print(nameInput);
      }
```

By `naem.length()`, you will get the length of the string.